# Spring MVC 3 Return Content-Type: text/plain

Tags: java, spring-mvc, content-type, apache-tiles

I want to display simple text on a page and as such I want to return the `Content-Type` as `text/plain`.

Using the code below, I see plain text on the page, however the return `Content-Type` is still `text/html`.

How can I fix this?

NOTE: I'm using Tiles with Spring MVC. The returned "m.health" points to a tiles def that maps to a health.jsp which only contains the 1 line below.

**UPDATE NOTE**: I have no control over the `Content-Type` or `Accept` values in the HTTP Header request. I want my response to return `text/plain` no matter what kind of request comes in.

Controller:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/m/health", method = RequestMethod.GET, headers = "Accept=*")
public String runHealthCheck(HttpServletResponse response, HttpServletRequest request, Model model) throws Exception {
    model = executeCheck(request, response, TEMPLATE, false, model);
    model.addAttribute("accept", "text/plain");
    response.setContentType("text/plain");
    response.setCharacterEncoding("UTF-8");
    return "m.health";
}
```

JSP:

> ${status}

Answer (score 58):

It should work if you annotate your method additionally with @ResponseBody:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/",
                method = RequestMethod.GET)
@ResponseBody
public String plaintext(HttpServletResponse response) {
    response.setContentType("text/plain");
    response.setCharacterEncoding("UTF-8");
    return "TEXT";
}
```

Comment: For anyone visiting this question, Markus added his reply after Ali accepted, but this is the correct approach when using annotations. It is simple and works well.

Comment: It does not work. If you use @ResponseBody, Spring will rewrite Content Type by "application/json"

Comment: This didn't work for me either.  For me, it's still coming out as "text/html".

Comment: Doesn't work for me. I get a 404 error (which contains the returned string.)

Comment: For anyone else replying here that it doesn't work, this IS the correct approach, and will work by _default_. [Review the documentation on the StringHttpMessageConverter](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/html/remoting.html#rest-string-converter) for more information.

Comment: I still have `application/json` type in response. I guess because i have Jackson in the classpath.

Answer (score 10):

You could try to set the `produces` value of your `@RequestMapping` annotation with `text/plain`. The Spring documentation lists this as a [sample](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/html/mvc.html#mvc-ann-requestmapping-produces).

Comment: I have no control over what `Content-Type` is set in the `request` and produces will not match if the request type is not what I set in it. I basically want to return `text/plain` no matter what the request type is.