# how to make the response as .txt file from @Responsebody annotation using the spring3.0

Tags: spring-mvc

![enter image description here][1]

can any one please explain me how to achieve this output using spring 3.x
when i clicked on a button i want to submit the data to the server and getting the response as text(.txt) file from the spring controller 3.x using the @ResponseBody annotation...

Comment: please post the code you tried till now if any.

Comment: Where did that image go?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try to write your `@ResponseBody` method like this

```
@ResponseBody
@RequestMapping(value ="/txt" )
public String txtResponse(HttpServletResponse response){
    String fileName = "a.txt";
    response.setHeader("Content-Disposition", "attachment; filename=" + fileName);
    String content = "This is txt content";
    return content;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

This looks very similar to:
[Spring MVC 3 Return Content-Type: text/plain](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8951534/spring-mvc-3-return-content-type-text-plain) and
[Who sets response content-type in Spring MVC (@ResponseBody)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3616359/who-sets-response-content-type-in-spring-mvc-responsebody/)

You should be able to set the Content-Type header of your response via @RequestMapping:

```
@RequestMapping(..., produces = org.springframework.http.MediaType.TEXT_PLAIN)
```

Which requires the client to pass in a Content-Type header to match.

Or by setting the header directly on your response object in your service method, like in: https://stackoverflow.com/a/5268157/1546662.

Or by adding a new message converter to the spring context, as noted in: https://stackoverflow.com/a/3617594/1546662

Comment: In my @RequestMapping it is showing no produces option available.Any way i got my answer thanks for the response....it is also usefull for another work....

Answer (score 0):

A better solution seems

```
public ResponseEntity<Resource> exportTemplate() throws IOException {
    return ResponseEntity.ok().header("Content-Disposition", "inline;filename=" + "filename.txt")
            .body(new ByteArrayResource(new pojoObject()));
}
```