# Spring4 @ResponseBody set default charset to utf8 with StringHttpMessageConverter

Tags: spring, rest, utf-8, spring-java-config

I am trying to return plain text message using ajax and rest.

Here is my controller for that:

```
@RequestMapping(value="/test", method=RequestMethod.PUT)
@ResponseBody
public String ajaxTest() {
    return "Characters test: ęółąśżźćń";
}
```

But unfortunatelly I am getting:

```
  Characters test: ?�???????
```

I know that I have to make StringHttpMessageConverter to use UTF-8 charset as default.
Even I have some xml configuration to it
https://jira.spring.io/browse/SPR-9099

```
<bean id="stringConverter" class="org.springframework.http.converter.StringHttpMessageConverter">
  <property name="supportedMediaTypes" value="text/plain;charset=UTF-8"/>
</bean>
```

but I use Java config instead of xml conf.

Here is my initializer;

```
public class Initializer implements WebApplicationInitializer {


    @Override
    public void onStartup(ServletContext servletContext) throws ServletException {
        AnnotationConfigWebApplicationContext ctx = new AnnotationConfigWebApplicationContext();
        ctx.register(WebAppConfig.class);
        ctx.register(ThymeleafConfig.class);
        servletContext.addListener(new ContextLoaderListener(ctx));

        ctx.setServletContext(servletContext);

        Dynamic servlet = servletContext.addServlet("dispatcher", new DispatcherServlet(ctx));
        servlet.addMapping("/");
        servlet.setAsyncSupported(true);     
        servlet.setLoadOnStartup(1);
        // Allow to use Put and Delete method for REST architecture
        registerCharachterEncodingFilter(servletContext);
        registerHiddenFieldFilter(servletContext);

    }


    private void registerCharachterEncodingFilter(ServletContext aContext) {
        CharacterEncodingFilter cef = new CharacterEncodingFilter();
        cef.setForceEncoding(true);
        cef.setEncoding("UTF-8");
        aContext.addFilter("charachterEncodingFilter", cef).addMappingForUrlPatterns(null ,true, "/*");
    }
    private void registerHiddenFieldFilter(ServletContext aContext) {
        aContext.addFilter("hiddenHttpMethodFilter", new HiddenHttpMethodFilter()).addMappingForUrlPatterns(null ,true, "/*"); 
    }
    private StringHttpMessageConverter stringConverter(ServletContext aContext) {
        StringHttpMessageConverter shmc = new StringHttpMessageConverter();
        shmc.setSupportedMediaTypes(Arrays.asList(new MediaType("text", "plain", Charset.forName("UTF-8"))));
        return shmc;
    }
}
```

but I can make it work. Please help.

Answer (score 1):

**EDITED**

Try this:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/find", produces = {"application/json; charset=UTF-8"})
@ResponseBody
public String find() {

    return "áéíóúÁÉÍÓÚ";

}
```

---

And add this in your web.xml

```
<filter>
    <filter-name>encoding-filter</filter-name>
    <filter-class>
        org.springframework.web.filter.CharacterEncodingFilter
    </filter-class>
    <init-param>
        <param-name>encoding</param-name>
        <param-value>UTF-8</param-value>
    </init-param>
    <init-param>
        <param-name>forceEncoding</param-name>
        <param-value>true</param-value>
    </init-param>
</filter>
<filter-mapping>
    <filter-name>encoding-filter</filter-name>
    <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
</filter-mapping>
```

Comment: Gives me http error: "not acceptable" (HTTP Status 406). In $.ajax method I dont have declared field: "contentType"

Comment: You'll need to add
 headers: { 
            'Accept': 'application/json',
            'Content-Type': 'application/json',
            'X-CSRF-TOKEN': '${_csrf.token}'
        },
to your ajax call.

Answer (score 0):

add defaultCharset UTF-8 like this because default StringHttpMessageConverter use charset  ISO-8859

```
<bean class="org.springframework.http.converter.StringHttpMessageConverter">
                <property name="writeAcceptCharset" value="false" />
                <property name="defaultCharset" value="UTF-8"/>
</bean>
```